# How to avoid specifying arguments for a class template with default template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments, class-template, ctad

If I am allowed to do the following:

```
template <typename T = int>
class Foo{
};
```

Why am I not allowed to do the following in main?

```
Foo me;
```

But I must specify the following:

```
Foo<int> me;
```

C++11 introduced default template arguments and right now they are being elusive to my complete understanding.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

***Note:***

`Foo me;` without template arguments is legal as of C++17. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970942/539997.

***Original answer applicable before C++17:***

You have to do:

```
Foo<> me;
```

The template arguments must be present but you can leave them empty.

Think of it like a function `foo` with a single default argument. The expression `foo` won't call it, but `foo()` will. The argument syntax must still be there. This is consistent with that.

Comment: @Pubby I suppose it would create some unnecessary complications if `Foo` *might* be a template identifier or *might* be an explicit instantiation depending on whether there's a default argument. Better keep the explicit instantiation syntax. Think of it like a function `foo` with a single default parameter. You can't call it like `foo`, you call it with `foo()`. It makes sense to keep this consistent.

Comment: @sftrabbit but you can't call a function with no arguments like `foo` either; you can name a class with no arguments as `Foo` however.

Comment: @aschepler I'm only guessing that they were trying to be consistent, not that they actually are. :D

Comment: @SethCarnegie But that's a class, this is a template. If you instantiate a template, you must give the template arguments (except the situation noted by @aschepler). I know, not the best of arguments.

Comment: @aschepler With a function, the template arguments can be deduced from the function arguments. With a class, it's not possible to decide, whether you meant a template class with default arguments or a non template class.

Comment: @OlafDietsche but you can't have a template class and a non-template class with the same name, so the compiler should be able to decide by just looking at what the name is.

Comment: @Pubby The standard committee asked themselves the same, I guess. Now, with C++17, the `<>` is no more necessary in this case. Check out my answer for more details.

Comment: It stinks that I can't convert code that uses a Matrix class with floats, and decide later to change it to Matrix<typename T=float> so double's can also be used w/o breaking old code. Std committee got this one wrong.

Answer (score 116):

With C++17, you can indeed.

This feature is called [class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and add more flexibility to the way you can declare variables of *templated types*.

So,

```
template <typename T = int>
class Foo{};

int main() {
    Foo f;
}
```

is now [legal C++ code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WEDMxX2C4G19yujd).

Comment: Strange. Just tried it in my C++17 project and it didn't work: "template placeholder type ‘const MyType’ must be followed by a simple declarator-id". I am using GCC 7.3.0.

Comment: @Silicomancer It's hard to say without seeing your code and command line... Maybe are you dealing with pointers [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085683/template-argument-deduction-for-class-templates-in-c17-am-i-doing-it-wrong)?

Comment: Clang doesnt accept it seems? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5d3c0f90ed263c2

Comment: @Borgleader Apparently, Coliru is using clang 5.0. Judging by [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), it should support C++17 template argument deduction, but evidently id doesn't. If you try your very same example in [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4kW9NzRUq9pvUJJS) using clang 7.0, it works flawlessly.

Comment: @PaoloM Oh cool, glad to know its just a compiler version issue. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: While the class template argument deduction as introduced by C++17 works well with GCC 8.X onwards it leads to a bug in GCC 7.X when combining default template data types and constant overloading (http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/const-overloading.html). Consider the following example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/YoFIUEYNXZ80D6UN
Even though one might expect the last instance "WhatAboutMe" to be a constant object it calls the non-constant implementation of "Method". As a consequence e.g. operators are able to change members of this seemingly constant object.

Comment: This should be top answer - the top answer is outdated.

Comment: In short: You need at least gcc 7.0+ (ideally 8.0+) or clang 7.0+.

Answer (score 32):

You are not allowed to do that but you can do this

```
typedef Foo<> Fooo;
```

and then do

```
Fooo me;
```

Comment: is there any difference in this with a default type and: `typedef Foo<float> Fooo;`, without a default type?

Comment: The C++11-ish way would be to say `using Fooo = Foo<>;`

Answer (score 22):

You can use the following:

```
Foo<> me;
```

And have `int` be your template argument. The angular brackets are necessary and cannot be omitted.

Comment: Makes sense and thank you but, as noted below, why do the type specifies have ot be present?

Comment: @user633658: Did you mean "type specifier"? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Anyway, concerning the reason behind the need for empty angular brackets, I can only make conjectures, and they're all about ruling out possible ambiguities with the usage of the template's name alone, but I have to confess that I do not know the exact reason

Comment: I strongly suspect the requirement for the <> is to enable the compiler's parser to determine that you are referring to a templated class called foo, rather than something else called foo.

Answer (score 0):

*Somewhat* different case and rather later but where a template *function* is involved.  [gcc 11.2 can't seem](https://godbolt.org/z/eY7x3MojP) to compile this:

```
template <typename T = int>
struct Test {};
template<typename T> void foo(T& bar) {}
int main()
{
    Test t;
    foo<Test>(t);
}
```

but [has no problem with](https://godbolt.org/z/bfoq9bjo4)

```
template <typename T = int>
struct Test {};
template<typename T> void foo(T& bar) {}
int main()
{
    Test t;
    foo<Test<>>(t);
}
```

Of course

```
template <typename T = int>
struct Test {};
template<typename T> void foo(T& bar) {}
int main()
{
    Test t;
    foo(t);
}
```

[works](https://godbolt.org/z/4oracroMT) - but sometimes you need to explicitly force the type.  Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Note that this depends on compiler version - your third sample doesn't work in C++14 but works in C++17.

This appears to be down to C++ language spec, not compiler error.

Specifically, if you're going to *partially* specify a template (e.g. `foo<Test>(t)`), you *need* to provide <> for every defaulted template - however just putting `foo(t)` works fine.

Comment: The answer gives additional information, but it appears to be speculative or partially a question itself.

Comment: The actual usage that provoked this "questionable answer" requires the template argument.  In that case it's not a partial specialization. I think that's actually the same case here - it is fully specialized.  I believe there's another reason why this doesn't compile (but thanks for your comment).

Comment: I threw in this queston: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71683140/defaulted-template-in-template-function-requires-empty-angle-brackets

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31414482)

Answer (score -1):

As per the `C++17` Standard, template arguments are necessary to be passed.

But if you still want a way around this, you can use `using` keyword like this

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Foo{
};
using IFoo=Foo<int>
```

Or, you can also use `preprocessor` like this

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Foo{
};

#define IFoo Foo<int>
```

***Quick Reminder***

> Preprocessors are bad for debugging.

Comment: This is plain worse than `using IFoo=Foo<int>`. Macro's ignore namespaces