# Class template with one parameter and default value

Tags: c++, templates

I must be missing something obvious here because this really came to me as a surprise.

The following code gives me the error: `error: missing template arguments before ‘a’`

```
template<int n=0>
class A {};

...
A a;
...
```

Is there a reason why a template with 1 parameter declared with a default value has to be instantiated specifying a value for it?

Can someone quote the standard?

Comment: you don't need to specify it: `A<> a;`

Comment: @W.F. Interesting, do you know why?.

Comment: similarly you can't call function with defaulted argument without braces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373823/template-default-arguments)

Comment: @imreal `A` isn't a class, it's a template. It makes no sense to declare a variable of a template -- you want a *particular instantiation*.  `<>` is the clue to the compiler that you're trying to instantiate a template, just as W.F. points out that `()` is the clue that you're trying to invoke a function (even if you aren't passing any arguments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A` is still a template class. But you can omit the template parameter though:

```
template<int n=0>
class A {};

int main() {
    A<> a;
  // ^^ 
    return 0;
}
```

See the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1878b853b3d1bd9d).

---

I think<sup>1</sup> the relevant [standard section](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf?raw=true) is here

> ## 14.7 Template instantiation and specialization
>
> ...
>   3 An explicit specialization may be declared for a function template, a class template, a member of a class
>   template or a member template. An explicit specialization declaration is introduced by template<>. In
>   an explicit specialization declaration for a class template, a member of a class template or a class member
>   template, the name of the class that is explicitly specialized shall be a simple-template-id. In the explicit specialization declaration for a function template or a member function template, the name of the function
>   or member function explicitly specialized may be a template-id.
>   *[Example:*
>
> ```
>  template<class T = int> struct A {
>      static int x;
>  };
>  template<class U> void g(U) { }
>  template<> struct A<double> { }; // specialize for T == double
>  template<> struct A<> { }; // specialize for T == int
>  template<> void g(char) { } // specialize for U == char
>  // U is deduced from the parameter type
>  template<> void g<int>(int) { } // specialize for U == int
>  template<> int A<char>::x = 0; // specialize for T == char
>  template<class T = int> struct B {
>      static int x;
>  };
>  template<> int B<>::x = 1; // specialize for T == int
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Sorry, I can't find a better standard cite / example. It doesn't cover exactly the OP's case, but demonstrates at least the same, that templates still need the `<>` angle brackets to be identified as templates (classes or functions).</sub>

Comment: This section of the standard is more about specializing templates. I don't see anything here about instantiating templates.

Comment: @cdhowie I gave up searching. Didn't find a better cite / example.

Answer (score 3):

possible workaround if it's important to disguise the nature of your object:

```
// the template class
template<int n=0>
class ReallyA {};

// an alias for the common case    
using A = ReallyA<0>;

A a;
```

This is how the standard library defines `std::string`, for example.

```
using string = basic_string<char>;
```