# How to turn a class into a template class without breaking existing client code (pre c++17)?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

Can I turn a class into a template class without breaking user code? I am trying to change a class to accept template parameters, but at the same time, I would like to avoid breaking existing client code. In more detail, the existing codebase was

```cpp
class A{ // some code };
```

I turned this into the following:

```cpp
template <type T = defaultType>
class A{ // some code };
```

The non-templatized code was effectively written for `defaultType`. Can I do anything so that existing code does not break when the code is compiled without c++17 (or greater) support? For example, the following should be valid:

```
A a{}; //existing code; works under c++17 with CTAD. How to use in c++14?
A<typeFoo> b{} //new code, if users decide to use a different template argument;
```

I am grateful for any hints or suggestions!

Comment: How is your question related to CTAD? I can't see any argument which will be deduced ( construcors are not taking arguments in your example...

Comment: @Klaus: I was wondering the same, and it is not mentioned, for example, in Nicolai  Josuttis' book.  However, see the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373823/template-default-arguments/50970942#50970942). I also tried it with my gcc 10 and it works.

Comment: CTAD won’t save you if you have parameters or members of, or pointers or references to, that type anywhere.  So C++17 surely doesn’t matter here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what `std::string` does:

```
template <typename T>
class basic_A{ ... };

using A = basic_A<defaultType>;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Caleth! You accidentally also helped me understand  `basic_string`.