# Defaulted Template in Template Function Requires Empty Angle Brackets <>

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, default-template-argument

[gcc 11.2 can't seem](https://godbolt.org/z/eY7x3MojP) to compile this:

```
template <typename T = int>
struct Test {};
template <typename T> void foo(T& bar) {}
int main()
{
    Test t;
    foo<Test>(t);
}
```

but [has no problem](https://godbolt.org/z/bfoq9bjo4) with

```
template <typename T = int>
struct Test {};
template <typename T> void foo(T& bar) {}
int main()
{
    Test t;
    foo<Test<>>(t);
}
```

Is this a compiler bug?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373823/template-default-arguments) seems to suggest it should work.

Comment: FYI, the actual use-case that led to this is a bit more complex.  I'll add some detail of that when I have time soon.

Answer (score 7):

GCC is right. An empty template argument list, `<>` for a *function* template is allowed to be omitted ([[temp.arg.explicit]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#4)). In other cases, the template argument list is generally required in order to name a particular specialization of a template, even if it is empty. See the grammar for *simple-template-id*, [[temp.names]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#1).

As a limited exception to the rule, if the name of a class template *without* a template argument list appears in a context where a concrete type is required, it is known as a "placeholder for a deduced class type" and this is only allowed in specific contexts listed in [[dcl.type.class.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct). The most common one is a variable declaration like `std::pair p("foo", 1)` where the compiler will deduce `std::pair<const char*, int>` in C++17 and later.

In your code, you are trying to refer to a particular specialization of class template `Test`, without specifying the template argument list, and not in a context where the template arguments can be deduced. Therefore, it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The new [Class template argument deduction (CTAD) (since C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) is applied to declarations. The expression `foo<Test<>>(t);` is not a declaration, it is a template function call.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code snippet, you specify a class template (`Test`) as a template parameter to `foo` and not a type (like an instance of a class template). You would need a function that takes a template template parameter to handle that.

Example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<template<class> class T, class U> // T = Test, U = deduced to int
void foo(T<U>& bar) {
    std::cout << std::is_same<T<U>, Test<int>>::value << '\n'; // true
}

int main() {
    Test t;
    foo<Test>(t); // now ok
}
```

In your second snippet, `foo<Test<>>(t);` instantiates `foo<Test<int>>(Test<int>&);` since `<>` makes the template instantiation use the default type for the template parameter, which is `int`.

Comment: This sounds reasonable and works: https://godbolt.org/z/1vKf4x1Wr
But with foo<Test<long>>(t) it doesn't https://godbolt.org/z/1vKf4x1Wr
That surprises and confuses me.

Comment: @Radrich You still need the overload that takes a _type_ if you want both to work. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/zGTrbYEhT)